# JavaScript. Changing generated radio buttons from written to HTML from loop to different types of inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the JavaScript below, there is an array of objects that creates quiz questions. The `buildQuiz()` function loops over the questions & with each iteration adds a radio button to each question. Is there a way to access certain questions to add different inputs? I have tried to select array indexes, but had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
// Functions
function buildQuiz() {
// variable to store the HTML output
const output = [];

// for each question...
myQuestions.forEach(
    (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

        // variable to store the list of possible answers
        const answers = [];

        // and for each available answer...
        for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {

            // ...add an HTML radio button
            answers.push(
                `<label>
        <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
        ${letter} :
        ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
        </label>`
            );
        }

        // add this question and its answers to the output
        output.push(
            `<div class="slide">
        <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
        <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
    </div>`
        );
    }
);

// finally combine our output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}


function showResults() {

// gather answer containers from our quiz
const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');

// keep track of user's answers
let numCorrect = 0;

// for each question...
myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

    // find selected answer
    const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
    const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
    const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;

    // if answer is correct
    if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
        // add to the number of correct answers
        numCorrect++;

        // color the answers green
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = 'lightgreen';
    }
    // if answer is wrong or blank
    else {
        // color the answers red
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = 'red';
    }
});

// show number of correct answers out of total
resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} out of ${myQuestions.length}`;
}

function showSlide(n) {
slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active-slide');
slides[n].classList.add('active-slide');
currentSlide = n;
if (currentSlide === 0) {
    previousButton.style.display = 'none';
} else {
    previousButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) {
    nextButton.style.display = 'none';
    submitButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
} else {
    nextButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
    submitButton.style.display = 'none';
}
}

function showNextSlide() {
showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function showPreviousSlide() {
showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

// Variables
const quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
const myQuestions = [{
    question: "Who invented JavaScript?",
    answers: {
        a: "Douglas Crockford",
        b: "Sheryl Sandberg",
        c: "Brendan Eich"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
},
{
    question: "Which one of these is a JavaScript package manager?",
    answers: {
        a: "Node.js",
        b: "TypeScript",
        c: "npm"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
},
{
    question: "Which tool can you use to ensure code quality?",
    answers: {
        a: "Angular",
        b: "jQuery",
        c: "RequireJS",
        d: "ESLint"
    },
    correctAnswer: "d"
},
{
    question: "Which of these is a popular Javascript Framework?",
    answers: {
        a: "Bootstrap",
        b: "Sass",
        c: "React"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
},
{
    question: "In CSS, the # selector is used to select which HTML element?",
    answers: {
        a: "ID",
        b: "Class",
        c: "List item"
    },
    correctAnswer: "a"
}
];

// Kick things off
buildQuiz();

// Pagination
const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
let currentSlide = 0;

// Show the first slide
showSlide(currentSlide);

// Event listeners
submitButton.addEventListener('click', showResults);
previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quiz"></div>
<input type="button" id="previous" value="Previous">
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Would tell there is not (at least simple) ;-) You can change myQuestions before page builds its form, but not after.

Comment: Anyway structure looks like this:
<div class="slide active-slide">
<div class="question"> Who invented JavaScript? </div>
<div class="answers"> <label>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="a">
a : Douglas Crockford
</label>
...</div>
</div>
<div class="slide">
<div class="question"> Which one of these is a JavaScript package manager? </div>
<div class="answers"> <label>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="a">
a : Node.js</label>
...</div>
</div>

Comment: So you can use these to get or set: document.getElementsByClassName("question")[no].innerHTML // question
document.getElementsByName("questionNo")[RadioNo].nextSibling.textContent // answer text
document.getElementsByName("questionNo")[RadioNo].value // answer letter

Comment: myQuestions[no].correctAnswer also in case you want to change whole thing :-)